# xml validation against xsd with DOM and SAX parser

Tags: xml, xsd

i am validating xml document with xsd. By using sax parser it successfully validates. But when we use DOM parser it gives error that 
" Validator Class: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'diagram'."

```js
**XSD File**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="xmlns:xsi" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="diagram">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        ----
        ----
        ----
        
        **XML File**
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<diagram xmlns="xmlns:xsi">
 <class name="Customer">
```

EDIT:

Simplified XSD (schema1.xsd)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="xmlns:xsi" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="diagram">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="class" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Simplified XML (xml1.xml):

```xml
<diagram xmlns="xmlns:xsi">
    <class>classe</class>
</diagram>
```

Minimal code to reproduce:

```java
// load document
// Get Document Builder
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

// Build Document
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("./resources/xml1.xml"));

SchemaFactory aSF = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = aSF.newSchema(new File("schema1.xsd"));
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

Source dsource = new DOMSource(doc);
validator.validate(dsource);
```

Comment: Show us how you invoke the validation.

Answer (score 0):

> your targetNamespace definition is unusual (it looks like a prefix
>   declaration in itself). Moreover it is using the 'reserved' xsi prefix
>   which is generally used by "Xml Schema Instance".
>
> Maybe the DOM validation is getting tricked by this "fake" xmlns:xsi
>   prefix somehow, can you try with another namespace value than
>   `xmlns:xsi` to see if you have different result ?

*EDIT*

After a bit of search, it is because the [DOM created is not namespace-aware](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1163). To fix it you should simply set your documentBuilder as namespace-aware:

```java
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

This was fixing the issue in my case.

Comment: i have changed the target name space but problem is as such. No validation, same error.

Comment: as stated in forty-two comment, can you show the code that calls the DOM validation ? Can you reproduce the issue with a minimalist xsd and xml version (like with only diagram element and one sub element in the inner sequence) ?

Comment: Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Validator Class: "
        + validator.getClass().getName());

      // validating the document against the schema
      validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Validation passed.");

Comment: try {
      String language = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
      SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
      schema = factory.newSchema(new File(name));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return schema;

Comment: try {
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory 
         = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      document = builder.parse(new File(name));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return document;

Comment: I can reproduce but do not find the issue. For me as you set up a targetnamespace it should also be the default namespace in the XSD file. But it does not change the error.

Comment: looks like it is ok with "factory.setNamespaceAware(true);" I edited my post